# Unity 5 c#, How to set a string variable equal to an InputField text?

Tags: c#, string, unity-game-engine

How can I set a string variable equal to an `InputField` text?

Picture of the situation:
[image: Picture]

C# Code:

```
public string Medlemsnr;
public Text MedlemsnrTEXT;

void Update()
{
     Medlemsnr = MedlemsnrTEXT.text;
}
```

Comment: is what you have done now not working? if not then try Medlemsnr = MedlemsnrTEXT.text.ToString();

Comment: No it is not working, it should work right?

Comment: did you try my recommendation ?

Comment: yes i did, still the same problem, the game just crash when i start it

Comment: When i debug the code in MonoDevelop it is all fine, but when i debug the game in Unity i get the error message: NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: can you provide the full error log within your question. Thanks

Comment: and are you sure you're calling the Update() method rather than accessing the reference directly

Comment: MedlemsnrTEXT is not an inputfield, also check that on the editor you reference the inputfield

Comment: I figured it out. i had to write it in separate void like this: public void { Medlemsnr = MedlemsnrTEXT.text}, and then assign it to the on end edit feauture in the inputfield

Comment: @user7642373 If you have solved this yourself, then you should post an answer for others to see.